# Power Bi add a custom row to a matrix for comparison

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, visualization, dax

I have a matrix in power bi. I want to add a row at the end with a constant value so that i can make comparisons with the other values. In excel we can just manually type out the last rows but how to achieve the same in PowerBi? In a line chart, i added a constant line from the analytics tab. Is it possible to do something similar for a matrix?
[image: I perform aggregate operations for years 2019 and 2018 based on month.I want the goal value(custom row which i manually entered in my excel sheet at the end after performing the calculations for both the years. I want it to be added at the end of my matrix in PowerBi]Is it possible to achieve this in Power Bi?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such option. You can create a query using 'Enter data' just with the additional row and append it to the main table